# Cannot find cache named in hazelcast

Tags: spring, caching, hazelcast

i am using hazelcast version 5.1.5 and when i use spring @Cacheable("cache_name") on top of my method when i call the method exception throws.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find cache named 'cache_name' for Builder[public java.util.List com.danial.user.management.service.UserService.getAllEntities2()] caches=[cache_name] | key='' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='' | sync='false';

here is my hazelcast configuration :

```
@Configuration
public class HazelcastConfig implements Serializable {

    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    private String appName;

    @Bean
    public Config CacheConfig() {
        Config config = new Config();

        config.setInstanceName("hazelcast_mwga_cluster");

        config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig()
                .addMember("172.16.20.113")
                .setEnabled(true);


        // Configure a Hazelcast instance for each map.
        config.addMapConfig(createMapConfig("cache_name"));
        return config;

    }

    @Bean
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() throws IllegalAccessException {
        return HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(createClientConfig());
    }

    private ClientConfig createClientConfig() throws IllegalAccessException {
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        clientConfig.setClusterName("hazelcast_mwga_cluster");
        clientConfig.setInstanceName("hazelcast_mwga_cluster");
        clientConfig.addNearCacheConfig(createNearCacheConfig());
        return clientConfig;
    }

    private NearCacheConfig createNearCacheConfig() {

        NearCacheConfig nearCacheConfig = new NearCacheConfig();
        nearCacheConfig.setInvalidateOnChange(true);
        nearCacheConfig.setInMemoryFormat(InMemoryFormat.OBJECT);
        return nearCacheConfig;
    }

    private MapConfig createMapConfig(String name) {
        MapConfig mapConfig = new MapConfig(name);
        //do the special config here
        NearCacheConfig nearCacheConfig = new NearCacheConfig();
        nearCacheConfig.setInMemoryFormat(InMemoryFormat.OBJECT);
        nearCacheConfig.setInvalidateOnChange(true);
        nearCacheConfig.setEvictionConfig(new EvictionConfig());
        mapConfig.setNearCacheConfig(nearCacheConfig);

        return mapConfig;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the **IllegalArgument** exception, you can see that the **cacheManager** is **empty**.

It should be an instance of **HazelcastCacheManager**. So the cache is not configured correctly.

Also you are creating both **Config** bean and **HazelcastInstance** with a **ClientConfig**

- **Config** is used for creating an Hazelcast cluster member

```
HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

- **ClientConfig** is used for connecting to Hazelcast cluster as client

```
HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
```

Create only of these beans.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the cache type. It sounds like Spring is looking for a *ICache* named `cache_name` and you have created an *IMap* with that name.

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70395899/what-is-the-formal-difference-between-a-cache-and-map-in-version-5-0-of-hazelcas) which is similar but not an exact duplicate.